# Am I learning anything from Project Euler if half my solutions are too slow?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic

The questions mostly seem to have two parts: first, figuring out how to approach the problem, what steps to take, what functions will be needed, what variables, counters, etc. etc., and second, optimizing that system to be able to handle gigantic numbers.

It seems if I just had a faster function to, say, find prime numbers, I would be able to plug it in my current "solutions" and go back and answer probably twenty or more questions I've had to skip because it would take an unreasonable time for my "solution" to get the answer (but it would get the answer). As it is, I've tried to come up with everything from scratch (that way I'm sure I understand how it works), and I'm sure my formulas are sub-optimal.

Is the second, optimization part, the whole challenge? Should I still be proud? Would it be cheating to look up some choice prime number and factorization functions and then copy-paste them into my current too-slow solutions?

Comment: It's not cheating to use other resources if you learn something when you do it.

Answer (score 3):

It's only cheating if *you* think it's cheating. I don't. In fact, I began my study of prime numbers and integer factorization exactly the same way you are doing now.

By the way, here's a simple function to find the prime numbers less than *n*; the algorithm was invented over two thousand years ago by Eratosthenes of Cyrene:

```
function primes(n)
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n
        if sieve[p]
            output p
            for i from p*p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
```

And here's a simple function to find the factors of a number *n* using trial division:

```
function factors(n)
    f := 2
    while f*f <= n
        while n % f == 0
            output f
            n := n / f
        f := f + 1
    if n <> 1 output f
```

There are ways to improve both functions. If you are interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.